# Any Plugin to generate flight seat map chart?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to know if there are any free plugin to generate flight seat map. I tried (http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-seat-charts-plugin), but I am not satisfied with it.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why am I getting -1 now?

Comment: To the "unknown" who put -1, please realize that this platform is also used for tech suggestions. If you don't have answer, just skip to other questions which you can answer. Else give reason why you are devoting the question

Comment: [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Wasn't the downvote but take a look at #4 in the off topic section.

Comment: Yes, Which is what I have told. I tried JSC, which dint satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 4):

**jQuery Seat Charts (JSC)**

jQuery Seat Charts (JSC) is a full-blown seat map library. It will generate an accessible map, legend, handle mouse & keyboard events and finally give you powerful selectors to control your map.

https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts